# What's the point of the [javascript-objects] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I've just noticed that we have a [javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-objects) tag. Objects are a fundamental part of the JavaScript language, representing pretty much everything -- if you don't know what a JavaScript object is, you don't know JavaScript at all. Is the tag *really* needed?

Comment: Seems useless. You have my burn vote.

Comment: The fact that objects are fundamental isn't really the point, is it? For OOP-specific JS questions, the tag seems useful. FWIW, we have several tags that relate to the fundamentals of a variety of general tags: javascript-events, css-selectors, python-import, etc.

Comment: @George Cummins: Perhaps the tag should be renamed to [javascript-oop] then.

Comment: @BoltClock Meh, either way. A random sampling of the question supports the notion that the rename would work. I'm not convinced that it is necessary, but wouldn't be opposed to it.

Comment: This sounds like it should be in Meta, since it's about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MathManiac: So I realised when I processed your second flag. :-) I'll clean these up.