# I object to [javascript-objects]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Can we burn [javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-objects)? [This was brought up nearly 2 years ago.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252824/whats-the-point-of-the-javascript-objects-tag) Can't these questions be tagged with JavaScript?

I think this tag should be burninated.

Comment: If I had a specific question about OOP in javascript, is there a better tag or tag combo to use?

Comment: @Will i would just say [tag:javascript] and maybe with the [tag:oop]

Comment: Maybe it should be made a synonym? Unfortunately it has a synonym of its own, so a moderator would have to do it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara sure!

Answer (score -2):

I don't agree with this particular request - the tag uniquely identifies a specific programming topic, it means the same thing in all common contexts, and it does add information to the post, so it really doesn't meet burnination criteria.

Comment: there's nothing special about javascript objects as compared to the other types of values that would warrant it having it's own tag. It provides no value to the questions it is applied to.

Comment: Why [javascript-objects] and not [javascript] [object]? There's more of the latter (>1500) than the former (~380)...